# Win32 determine process ID

Tags: winapi, process

I want to create a process in Win32 .NET can I determine FOR the OS which PID the application will get ?

Update:

1) I am asking it because I have a problem in which I have 2 .NET application (the same ones) that I have each one of them got parameter ID and I want using a script (using the parameter) to decide which is the one and get it's PID
2) I want to know it from out side not from the .NET Process. I need for a script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can never determine what PID a process will get.  You can only determine what PID a process did get after you start the process.

In .Net you can do the following

```
var newProcess = Process.Start(someExeFile);
var id = newProcess.Id
```

In Win32 the CreateProcess function will return an `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct as an out parameter of the function.  It has the new PID as one of it's members (dwProcessId)

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684873(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yes as I suspected. I am asking it because I have a problem in which I have 2 .NET application (the same ones) that I have each one of them got parameter ID and I want using a script (using the parameter) to decide which is the one and get it's PID.

Comment: Yes but I want to know it from out side not from the .NET Process.
I need for a script.